# How to make text into a transparent punch through a shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, transparency

I am a total newbee in Illustrator.

As in title said, I'd like to ask how to input transparent text in Adobe Illustrator.

For instance, the following image has 2 layers, one is the ring and the other is the text. Currently the text is white color. But what I actually want is to make it transparent (punch through the shape). I'm not sure how to do it. Anyone could give me some advice? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Transparent so that it looks slightly darker against the brown?

Comment: @WELZ No, the image here is just an example. The color here really doesn't matter. But I have found the solution already.

Answer (score 3):

I misunderstood what you were asking, just convert your text to outlines, and select all and make it into a compound path (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>).

A compound path is less destructive than pathfinder, and you can make changes later on if needed.

That will punch the text through as you want, but still allow for changes to be made in the future.

---

#### Old Answer

You can use the *Transparency Panel* to change the opacity/transparency of an object in Illustrator.

Go to **Window → Transparency** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>)

[image: Transparency Panel]

There you can select your object (the text group) and change it's transparency settings.

---

I may have misunderstood what you're asking, please let me know if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have found a solution already. Just use "Create Outlines" on the text. Then use the "Minus Front" in Pathfinder on the text and background image.

Comment: @S.Li I updated my answer with a better solution following your outlines, I hadn't initially understood what you were asking for.